Sort values in google sheet such that the new column will be a new row
Example, I have table



Name
Value1
Value 2
Value 3




XYZ
V1
V2



ABC
V3




PQR
V5

V12



I need output as:



Name
Value




XYZ
V1


XYZ
V2


ABC
V3


PQR
V5


PQR
V12



SO i tried Transpose in google sheet, but I guess my job is close but not done yet.
can you suggest me anything?

You need to unpivot your columns not transpose them.
Something like this should work :
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A3:A5&"&"&B2:D2&"&"&B3:D5);"&"));"select Col1,Col3 where Col3<>'' LABEL Col1 'Name',Col3 'Values'")



Another solution using REDUCE:
=REDUCE({"Name","Value"},TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(a,c,
   {a;IFNA(HSTACK(c,TOCOL(FILTER(B2:D,A2:A=c),1)),c)}))



INDEX it. SPLIT it by "♥". TOCOL it to remove blanks. IF B2:D is empty, do nothing, otherwise join A2:A & "♥" & B2:D.
done.
=INDEX(SPLIT(TOCOL(IF(B2:D="";;A2:A&"♥"&B2:D); 1); "♥"))

